# Map <-> struct type casting

Tags: go

Currently this is the method I use to convert map[string]interface{} to Message struct

```
byteBlob, err := json.Marshal(messageMap)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

message := &Message{}
err = json.Unmarshal(byteBlob, message)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

I found json package to hack my way through this, but what is the right way to do this conversion? obviously without using json package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `encoding/json` package makes use of the `reflect` package to marshal and unmarshal messages.

So you can do the same with `reflect` directly.  If you don't need the support for nested structs and arrays, the following should do the trick:

```
message := Message{}

v := reflect.ValueOf(&message).Elem()
for key, value := range messageMap {
    field := v.FieldByName(key)
    if !field.IsValid() {
        // or handle as error if you don't expect unknown values
        continue
    }
    if !field.CanSet() {
        // or return an error on private fields
        continue
    }
    field.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
}
```

You can experiment further with this code [in the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Jn8AMCRdhG).

Comment: Don't forget to check for `field.PkgPath` to be the empty string (exported fields). Trying to `Set` to an unexported field will panic.

Comment: Good point.  I've added a CanSet() check to the example code fragment.

Comment: There are also existent packages doing that magic. I haven't used it myself yet, but for example: https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure